# Please Help me with this PSpice CODE CIRCUIT

Tags: operational-amplifier, pspice, orcad, code

I have a circuit to implement in PSpice, but I am completely newbie. Can you help me with it ? Here is the picture of it. I have to make an AC analysis, with a a signal source of 100mV with the frequency between 10HZ and 100kHZ.

I also should find the gain of the filter and the cutting frequency of the filter. "AO" is an operational amplifier.

This is what I tried to do, but it does not work:

```
circuit_opamp
R1 2 1 2K
R2 2 1 2K
R3 3 2 1K
R5 4 0 10K
R4 5 4 5.86K
Vs 1 0 SIN(0 100m 50K)
C1 5 2 31.83n
C2 3 0 31.83n
XU1 4 3 5 opamp Aol=100K GBW=10Meg
.TRAN 0.01mS 5mS
.AC DEC 40 1k 10MEG
.end
```

[image]

Comment: What prevents you from reading the manual and/or following some tutorial on the Internet and/or consulting the class notes or book or handouts you got in class? Because **no one on earth** is expected to be able to do this without at least some instruction or at least reading the manual. Also "it does not work" is not telling us much now is it? **What** does not work?

Comment: Just a hint: R1 + R2 = 1K, so you have input resistors of equal value and C1 = C2. You have a simple Bessel filter with a gain of almost 2. Read a stack of books on op-amp filters or op-amps used as filters, then ask us better questions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
* V1 is your AC source under analysis
V1 2 0 AC 1
* V2 and V3 are needed to supply the opamp's rails
V2 1 0 15
V3 0 7 15
* Your five resistors
R1 3 2 2k
R2 3 2 2k
R3 6 3 1k
R4 4 5 5.86k
R5 5 0 10k
* And two capacitors
C1 4 3 31.83n
C2 6 0 31.83n
* And the opamp here
XU1 6 5 4 1 7 opampsubcktmodelname
* The AC analysis line; here 40pts per decade, from 1kHz to 10MHz
.ac dec 40 1k 10Meg
.end
```

But you don't write much, so it's hard to know what to add to this for you. All I did was replicate your schematic. You should have been able to do as well. It's not complicated.

Note the use of "AC 1" to help identify how the AC analysis is to be done.

Also note that I've used 5 nodes for the opamp and not three. It does need to be powered somehow, I imagine. (I've used \$\pm15\:\textrm{V}\$ supplies. You can use whatever you want there.) You can add your other parameters, as needed. I just wanted to get the basics down there.

If you want the .TRAN analysis, then replace V1's card with the sinusoidal description and use .TRAN instead of .AC.

Add *.PRINT AC* card for desired nodes in the output in the AC analysis. Or add *.PRINT TRAN* card for the desired nodes in the output in the TRAN analysis.

---

If you really do want to use some kind of ideal opamp circuit, you can create your own .SUBCKT for it with only three nodes required. Or use one from a library. But you didn't provide your example, so I went with the usual case you find.

I suppose a trivial 3-node opamp with Aol=100k might be:

```
.SUBCKT OPAMP 1 2 3
EGAIN 3 0 1 2 100k
.ENDS
```

If you want GBW, it gets more complicated.

In any case, it's up to you what .SUBCKT you wind up using and it is also up to you to make sure that you apply it properly in your circuit.

If you are relying on a library version, then you failed to provide it here. So again, it's difficult to make sure all the bits and pieces are lined up right if you provide an incomplete scenario.

---

Final note. There is absolutely no better book (in my experience) than "The Spice Book," by Andrei Vladimirescu. Get a copy and keep it with you. It's easy to read, clear, well organized, and answers most reasonable questions.

Comment: I don't use PSpice, but maybe you need a .PRINT or .PLOT line to actually push some data to the output file?

Comment: Now I see you mention that, but you might want to include it in your sample deck.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'd rather not. I've done enough damage. The OP really should just buy the book. It's a cakewalk to read.